# Excel VBA - UserForm Combobox with If Statement

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I've created an Userform. The code is not completed yet, but trying to have conditions on the combobox. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With SupText
        .AddItem "Sup1"
        .AddItem "Sup2"
        .AddItem "Sup3"
    End With
    
    With ProdText
        .AddItem "Prod1"
        .AddItem "Prod2"
        .AddItem "Prod3"
        .AddItem "Prod4"
        .AddItem "Prod5"
    End With
    
    With UnitText
        .AddItem "kL"
        .AddItem "T"
    End With
    
    With StaText
        .AddItem "In Progress"
        .AddItem "Awaiting"
        .AddItem ""
    End With
    
    With ProLText
        .AddItem "1"
        .AddItem "4"
        .AddItem "1&4"
        .AddItem "2"
        .AddItem "3"
        .AddItem "2&3"
        .AddItem "WOPL"
        .AddItem "BOPL"
        .AddItem "Industry Line"
    End With
    
    End Sub
```

So, what I'm trying to do is to `ProLText` combobox to populate the list according to the `SupText`. When I use an `if` statement it doesn't work. For instance, if the choose the Sup1 from SupText Combobox I would like to give only the first 6 option of the ProLText combobox, the Sup2 gives the next 2 and Sup3 the last item. But for some reason, it gives result on for the else statement and not for if or else if.

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the `.Style` of the comboboxes to `fmStyleDropDownList`
2. Do not add items to `ProLText` in the `UserForm_Initialize()`
3. In `SupText_Click()` event clear the `ProLText` and re-add relevant items.

**CODE**

```
Private Sub SupText_Click()
    If SupText.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
    
    ProLText.Clear
    
    Select Case SupText.Text
    Case "Sup1"
        With ProLText
            .AddItem "1"
            .AddItem "4"
            .AddItem "1&4"
            .AddItem "2"
            .AddItem "3"
            .AddItem "2&3"
        End With
    Case "Sup2"
        With ProLText
            .AddItem "WOPL"
            .AddItem "BOPL"
        End With
    Case "Sup3"
        With ProLText
            .AddItem "Industry Line"
        End With
    End Select
End Sub
```

Or a shorter version

```
Private Sub SupText_Click()
    If SupText.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
        
    With ProLText
        .Clear
        Select Case SupText.Text
            Case "Sup1"
                .AddItem "1"
                .AddItem "4"
                .AddItem "1&4"
                .AddItem "2"
                .AddItem "3"
                .AddItem "2&3"
            Case "Sup2"
                .AddItem "WOPL"
                .AddItem "BOPL"
            Case "Sup3"
                .AddItem "Industry Line"
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you sooooooo much! It works perfectly. I'm able now to add multiple level of statements. BTW, if you get a chance, could you pls explain me why the same code doesn't work `UserForm_Initialize()`? I'm still learning coding so I'm probably missing basics.

Comment: `UserForm_Initialize()` adds everything to the combobox in the begining. Think of it like putting all the food in the plate together. So take whatever you are eating now and then go back for the next helping ;)