# Filter dropdown list based on another dropdown list in userform

Tags: excel, vba

Thank you for viewing this request.

**Details:**

I have 2 lists: Category ID; Task ID.

There is a 1 to many relationship from Category ID --> Task ID, meaning that Task ID can be associated with only 1 Category ID; but, multiple Task IDs can share the same Category ID.

Category ID = Broader Description | Example: Continent: North America

Task ID = Granular Description | Example: Since North America was selected only Canada, 'Merica, and Mexico should populate, not the rest of the countries.

**Question:**

When creating a dropdown list in a user form, is it possible to for Country Dropdown list to be filtered based off of what was already selected in Continent dropdown list?

Images for Reference:

This is what I want it to look like but for user form in VBA

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make the Combobox item list dynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40612417/how-to-make-the-combobox-item-list-dynamic)

Comment: Answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66703205/excel-vba-userform-combobox-with-if-statement) a few days ago...

Comment: Might also be worth looking at? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64525859/how-to-select-a-dropdown-cell-validation-value/65153453#65153453